# Authentication with AngularFireAuth module

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following a tutorial that walks through the steps on authentication with Firebase. However, there is changes in the documentation. I am looking at this documentation: [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)

The following are my dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.8",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

In my app.module.ts file, I have imported the AngularFireAuth module as listed in the docs:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

Now the tutorial that I am looking at talks about adding the following. However, I don't see this in the documentation, and when I type it in VS Code, `AuthProviders` and `AuthMethods` are underlined in squiggly red:

```
const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Google,
  method: AuthMethods.Redirect

};
```

The tutorial also talks about adding firebaseAuthConfig in initializeApp:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
```

But again, I don't see this in the documentation.

So can someone pls guide me as to what I need to do to get my authentication working.

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: sure. here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7g_18idr_8&index=4&list=PLillGF-RfqbYftYr5T6bv9idBU7oyADoZ

Comment: Also, the tutorial refers to authentication from the way it was i guess a few months ago... i used `import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';` after checking out the documentation; but i wasn't able to quite follow the next steps from there.

Comment: Have you tried the [AngularFire auth guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)? Is there a problem with the official docs?

Comment: Im sure there is no problem.. ive followed the same, but im unable to figure out the way forward

Comment: ive been able to get this working. i had to import `import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';` and not just `import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';` as listed in the docs on github for angularfire2